# how to apply count in the following code, the code is running only for first page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId='

html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gvSearchDentistlist'})
try:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if len(row.find_all('td')) == 6:
            data = row.find_all('td')
            name = data[1].text.strip()
            print("NAME:"+name)
            root_url = data[5].input['onclick'].split(",")[4]
            link ='http://dciindia.gov.in/'+root_url
            print("LINK:"+link)
except:
    pass
```

I wrote this code but its giving output for only first page i want to run this code for all pages in the above site what to do? Please help

Comment: The pages on that site are navigated by calling Javascript which passes a page number argument, the pages seem _not_ accessible through a direct resource URL. You’ll have to find a way to trigger that click event in order to get to that next page…

Comment: i dont know how to click on the next page can you help me with  that @Jens

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of `javascript` `__doPostBack` in your webpage. Since no one pointed out on selenium as an alternative, here is an example of clicking the pages on your webpage using selenium:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

def your_func(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gvSearchDentistlist'})
    try:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            if len(row.find_all('td')) == 6:
                data = row.find_all('td')
                name = data[1].text.strip()
                print("NAME:"+name)
                root_url = data[5].input['onclick'].split(",")[4]
                link ='http://dciindia.gov.in/'+root_url
                print("LINK:"+link)
    except:
        pass


url = 'http://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId='

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'path\chromedriver.exe')

driver.maximize_window()

# first page
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
your_func(html)

# page 2
nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/fieldset/div/table/tbody/tr[52]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
nextPage.click()
html = driver.page_source
your_func(html)

# page 3
nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gvSearchDentistlist"]/tbody/tr[52]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a')
nextPage.click()
html = driver.page_source
your_func(html)
```

Comment: but if i have to run this code for 2000 pages then what to do? @SSharma

Comment: Yes, exactly so this alternative only works if you have few pages. In your website, the normal pagination is not possible as the url itself do not change itself.

Comment: any other solution?